# Tax implications of advance on a future tax refund

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, tax-credit, massachusetts

Pursuant to [M. G. L. c. 62F](https://malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartI/TitleIX/Chapter62F), there is a limit on the amount of taxes that the state of Massachusetts can collect in a given tax year. Section 2 provides that the taxes collected year over year cannot grow faster than than average wages and salaries in the state. This is rarely exceeded, but in tax year 2021, it was.

Thus, under section 6, "a credit... shall be applied to the then current personal tax liability of all taxpayers on a proportional basis to the personal income tax liability incurred by all taxpayers in the immediately preceding taxable year." I understand this to mean that the credit is non-refundable and may only be applied against 2022 taxes; however, the state has decided to distribute this credit in the form of checks mailed this fall to all 2021 taxpayers.

What are the tax implications of this bizarre disbursement on state and federal taxes? Will someone who otherwise would owe less Massachusetts income tax in 2022 than the amount of their distribution (that is, someone who as a result of this advance credit disbursement will have a negative tax balance at the end of the year) be required to repay the difference?